# Topology of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$

Tags: general-topology, product-space

I want to know which is the topology of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$, but I don't know even how to start to give it one. How can I give to $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ a topology? Is there a book that explains this?

Comment: I guess the book *Topology* by J.Munkres should explain in more detail this space.

Comment: Or does $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ refer to the **Alexandroff compactification** (or one-point-compactification) $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$? Then the topology of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ would be given by the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ plus all sets $\mathbb{R}-C\cup \{\infty\}$ where $C\subset\mathbb{R}$ is conmpact and closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Surb That question asks for a definition of $\Bbb{R}^\infty$ in the special case we want to give it the structure of a CW-complex. While it is very likely that this question has been asked and answered earlier I'm not sure that's the right dupe target.

Answer (score 2):

There are two standard topologies on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$. (You have to be careful with the notion $\infty$ I assume it means countable infinity so just write $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$).

The first topology is called the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) and is the more common than the other one. One can define this topology by forcing that $x_n\rightarrow x$ if and only if every coordinate of $x_n$ converges to the corresponding coordinate of $x$ (i.e. point-wise convergence).

The second topology is called the [box topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology). This topology is less common. One can define this topology by forcing that $x_n\rightarrow x$ if each coordinate converges to $x$ uniformly (i.e. they convergence pointwise but the big $N$ is only dependent on the $\varepsilon$ and is not dependent on the coordinate).